# Span dentro de @Html.ActionLink

Tags: html, css, razor, span

Tenho a seguinte coluna de uma tabela:

```
<td style="font-size:10%">
   <p class="list-group-item-text">
      @Html.ActionLink((string)item.cidadenome, "Cidade", "Cidade", new { cidadecod = item.cidadecod, contratocod = item.contratocod }, new { @class = "list-group-item active", @style = "font-size: 18px" } )
      <span class="badge" style="font-size: 12px; background-color:@item.statusservidor_stts">
          @item.statusservidor
      </span>
    </p>
</td>
```

Porém o conteúdo do Span é exibido abaixo do ActionLink, como ilustrado na imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de que o Span fosse exibido, no Action Link (na parte azul) após o número. O que devo fazer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@Url.Action` ao invés de `@Html.ActionLink`:

```
<td style="font-size:10%">
   <p class="list-group-item-text">
      <a href="@Url.Action("Cidade", "Cidade", new { cidadecod = item.cidadecod, contratocod = item.contratocod })" class = "list-group-item active", style = "font-size: 18px">
          @item.cidadenome
          <span class="badge" style="font-size: 12px; background-color:@item.statusservidor_stts">
              @item.statusservidor
          </span>
      </a>
   </p>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use o `@Url.Action` ele monta a URL para você dinamicamente com os parâmetro passado.

Eu prefiro ao criar link usar o `@Url.Action` do que o `@Url.ActionLink` pois visualmente ficar mais fácil de alguém que não conhece os HELPERS do Razor entende que ali tem um link e `@Url.Action` retorna uma URL